# One Akka actor per database entity?

Tags: database, akka, actor

Is it common practice to have one Akka actor per database entity? i.e. is it meant to be used like this?

Say we have tens of thousands of users and for each, logged in, user at our Play-website we create one actor with child actors representing related data out of a relational database.
[actors vs. entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IGr2.png)

Is there a better approach? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at akka actor system documentation http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/general/actor-systems.html

> A common pattern is to create a router for N actors, each of which wraps a single DB connection and handles queries as sent to the router. The number N must then be tuned for maximum throughput, which will vary depending on which DBMS is deployed on what hardware.

Comment: So to expand on that - actors are there to distribute workflow, an actor representing a DB connection makes sense (besides DB connections are limited while users are not) to limit simultanously processed queries. An actor per DB entity seems a misconception, why handle DB entities asynchronously?

Comment: Thanks Mario and Tomasz for clarifiying. You saved me days I better spend with my son.